# Pythonic reading from config files

Tags: python, coding-style, configparser, dry

I have a python class which reads a config file using ConfigParser:

Config file:

```
[geography]
Xmin=6.6
Xmax=18.6
Ymin=36.6
YMax=47.1
```

Python code:

```
class Slicer:
    def __init__(self, config_file_name):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(config_file_name)
        # Rad the lines from the file
        self.x_min = config.getfloat('geography', 'xmin')
        self.x_max = config.getfloat('geography', 'xmax')
        self.y_min = config.getfloat('geography', 'ymin')
        self.y_max = config.getfloat('geography', 'ymax')
```

I feel that the last four lines are repetitive, and should somehow be compressed to one Pythonic line that would create a `self.item` variable for each item in the section.

Any ideas?

Adam

**UPDATE:**

Following your answers, I've modified my code to:

```
    for item in config.items('geography'):
        setattr(self, '_'+item[0], float(item[1]))
```

Now,

```
   print self.__dict__
   >>> {'_xmax': 18.600000000000001, '_ymax': 47.100000000000001, 
        '_ymin': 36.600000000000001, '_xmin': 6.5999999999999996}
```

Comment: Anyone see great potential for security vulnerabilities with this approach? Imagine some evil intention adding `_dict__=[<something dangerous here>]` line to your config. If `__dict__` is protected by a chance (I didn't try it in real) then there're plenty more of other `__XXX__` helpers that might get interfered. So, Rubayeet's and Michael's answers are way more perfect as following pythonic principle 'Explicit is better than implicit'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for line in ['x_min', 'x_max', 'y_min', 'y_max']:

   setattr(self, line, config.getfloat('geography', line.replace('_', '')))
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually try to avoid external interactions in a constructor - makes it hard to test the code. Better pass a config parser instance or a fp-like object instead of a filename.

Comment: +1: Reading a config is not part of the constructor.  Pass the open file to a method.  Do not secretly open a file.  If you pass an opened file object to a method, you can easily construct a unit test that doesn't secretly depend on a secret file.

Comment: They want your class to function more like `s = Slicer(file); s.parse()`.  As opposed to doing it all in the config.  It becomes hard to test individual methods and functionality in a unittest, if a lot of the functionality takes place in the init.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
for key in ['xmin','xmax','ymin','ymax']:
    self.__dict__[key] = config.getfloat('geography',key);
```

Note that the above will assign it to self.xmin instead of self.x_min... however, if you are fine with that naming, then this should work... otherwise, mapping between names would be more code than the original.